# JS | Вопрос по наследованию

Tags: javascript

Смотрю уроки по JS о прототипном наследовании, код почти тот же как у автора, однако у него всё работает. В чем может быть проблема? Что не так с наследованием? Вопрос в коде.

```js
var Humans = function(params) {
 this.tribe = params.tribe;
 this.race = params.race;
};


 Humans.prototype.present = function() {
 console.log('We are ', this.race + ' of tribe ' , this.tribe);
 };

var inner = function(params) {
 Humans.apply(this, arguments);  
}

var Aborigine = new Humans({race: "Aborigines", tribe: "Afriha"});
Aborigine.present();

var Hunters = new inner({race: "Black", tribe: "Afar"});
Hunters.present();  /* выдает ошибку, почему? "Hunters.present это не функция" */
```

Comment: _Humans.apply_ добавит в `this` только поля, которые определяются внутри функции _Humans_. А метод _present_ находится в прототипе этой функции. Подробнее в ответе по ссылке на дубликат

Comment: упс, да, сорри, тупанул

Comment: В дубликате хорошее описание наследования: что как и почему